# cannot access Zend projects after uninstalling and re-installing wamp

Tags: zend-framework, wamp, wampserver

I uninstalled WAMP in error, then downloaded and reinstalled a new one, same version. Having looked through the WAMP directories, I can see that my databases are still intact(I think) and I can access them through a MYSQL client. But I am unable to access my projects as before the accidental uninstal. My projects are Zend. I have set PHP include_path on the new PHP installation to point to ZendFramework library folder and to WAMP "www" folder. I have re-created new APACHE v-hosts to point to the old projects. These are the configurations I remember to do so far.

So I am unable to access my zend projects as I had on the old WAMP. I feel it is a configuration issue because all project files and directories seem to be intact just like the MYSQL files/directories. I keep getting

```
The requested URL /xyz/ was not found on this server
```

Edit: I can only access the home pages of these projects, but no other pages/sub-folders.

Comment: Perhaps `mod_rewrite` is not yet enabled on the new install?

Comment: @DavidWeinraub Zend projects automatically enable mod_rewrite

Comment: No, they don't. That's an Apache-level functionality. It's true that ZF projects *depend upon* `mod_rewrite`, which I suspect may be the problem here.

Comment: I tried mod_rewrite but it didn't help. Did you notice my edit? I can see the home(index) pages but no further pages/directories. That's where the server error report shows up.

Comment: Do you get an Apache-generated 404 or a ZF-generated 404? The error above looks like an Apache-generated one. Your situation really has all the earmarks of a not-yet-enabled `mod_rewrite`. If it were enabled, then the error would be generated by ZF. Try putting a blatant syntax error in your `public/.htaccess` file and see if your error page changes to Apache's 500 error.

Comment: The error is precisely as in the original post. I think it's an apache error report. I'd tried to influence what error is output by entering some gibberish in the `"public/.htaccess"` but with no effect, no change in error-message. I still access the index(home) page with no problem but cannot access any further pages.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23925/discussion-between-okeyxyz-and-david-weinraub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are having problem with apache configuration, find http.conf/httpd.conf. Find the entry within http.conf file, and ensure that ‘AllowOverride‘ and ‘Options‘ values are set to ‘All‘ (by default these are set to None). You can follow this [link](http://thiranjith.com/2010/09/14/how-to-setup-zend-framework-with-apache-on-windows/) move to step 4. apache configuration, that might help you.

Comment: I tried that, still no solution. It seems the former installation of wamp is not completely removed from my computer. Do you have an idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: I do not think former installation should give you any trouble, I have multiple wamp installations on my server and so far I have never had any problem regardless of other wamps. How about you create a virtual host for your zend application and give another try that might help.http://www.dennisplucinik.com/blog/2007/08/16/setting-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp/ donot forget to allowOverride all option on your VH.

Comment: Works fine now. But honestly this server seems to have a mind of it's own. I got it working by following the [blog](http://thiranjith.com/2010/09/14/how-to-setup-zend-framework-with-apache-on-windows/) you referred: enabling `mod_rewrite`, setting `AllowOverwrite All` and `Options All`. So I disable them one at a time to see what combination did it. Now only `mod_rewrite` gets it to work, even without `AllowOverwrite All` and `Options All`(commented-out\deleted). But I did try this same `mod_rewrite` countless times when @DavidWeinraub suggested it but with no effect.