# How to completely uninstall WAMPSERVER

Tags: zend-framework, wamp, uninstallation, wampserver

I recently uninstalled, then re-installed WAMP, But now my domains(zend projects) are malfunctioning. I can only access the front pages for these domains but not any further pages, which I explained in a previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677307/cannot-access-zend-projects-after-uninstalling-and-re-installing-wamp) Everything suggested on the thread and more have not worked so far.

So I have another idea from searching google which suggests that WAMP has not been completely uninstalled when I did the first uninstall, and the solution is to go to regedit after uninstall, do a search for "wamp" then delete all records related to wampserver. I'd done this but I'm getting 216-records and only three of them has a mention of "wamp" on the record names. I feel it can't be right to delete all 216-records and i'm scared because these records point to other programs and systems in windows. But this [blog](https://sites.google.com/site/drupaldebugmultisite/) seems to suggest that I delete them all as below:

> ...into the registry.  Highlight 'Computer' and press the [Ctrl][F]
>   key combination to launch a search box.  Type in 'wamp' as a search
>   term.  Delete all instances of a record pertaining to WampServer.  On
>   a healthy installation, there may be 70 such entries or more.  Just
>   grit your teeth and get it done, making sure all the while that the
>   search result is indeed a WampServer related entry...

I have deleted the 3-records I found with mentions of "wampserver", but yet no solution to my problem. So my question is: Could the instruction possibly be to delete the entire 216-records in order to completely clear my system of all traces of the old WAMP installation?

Comment: If you want someone to be able to help you successfully, post some code to help. There is lots of experience here to help you, but if you won't provide the info needed they can't help. POST a _vhost_, the area of your httpd.conf that shows where _mod_rewrite_ is uncommentted. Post your widows _hosts_ file and your current .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing WampServer should consist of:

- stopping and uninstalling the services (wampapache and wampmysql) either with the uninstall services batch file included or [on the command line](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-windows-service-in-vista-or-xp/)
- deleting the wamp folder

Bear in mind any changes to:

- Your web root folder(s)
- Your hosts files
- Your firewall

Now, if you've done the above and have problems still, it'll likely there are other problems. Such things as different httpd configs, .htaccess files, different versions of wampserver and components like PHP and it's modules, databases and their security credentials, etc.

Check the above, and if there are more specific errors feel free to post them too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your time. I think my actions as in the OP were successful in completely uninstalling wampserver. Just that my fresh instal of WAMP was mis-behaving and not finding pages beyond the home page. It's been sorted by enabling  `mod_rewrite`. Though I'm not quite sure what went wrong as I'd applied the same `mod_rewrite` severally without a resolution.